# Have a NSComboBox to update when its bound NSMutableArray updates

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscombobox

Let's say I have a window with 2 combo boxes. The `NSWindowController` that control the window, has two mutable arrays that are bound to the combo boxes Content Values.

What I would like is that while the first combo box has fixed values, the second combo values depends on the first combo selected value.

What should I do to have the second combo box to reload its content when the associated mutable array updates (Or how should I update the array to make this happen?)?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value of the second array through its normal accessor methods, the right update messages should be propagated to all bound values and other listeners.

```
// When first combo box changes value
// NSArray *newArray = // Fancy algorithm..
self.secondArray = newArray;
```

That should get the second combo box to update.

In case you do not want to change the instance of the `NSMutableArray` backing your property, you could use the mutable accessor methods, discussed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html). They will let you change the contents of the mutable array without changing the array itself. And the KVC/KVO system will propagate the changes to the listeners.